# How to upload a file with django-tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

### MODEL

```
class Post(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
created_at = models.BigIntegerField(default=int(time.time()))
edited_at = models.BigIntegerField(default=int(time.time()))
image = models.FileField(upload_to='/images/')
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

### API

```
class MultiPartResource(object):
   def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
       if not format:
           format = request.Meta.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
       if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
           return request.POST
       if format.startswith('multipart'):
           data = request.POST.copy()
           data.update(request.FILES)
           return data
       return super(MultiPartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)


class PostResource(MultiPartResource, ModelResource):

    profile = fields.ForeignKey(ProfileResource, 'profile')

    class Meta:
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'post'
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
    authorization = Authorization()
```

### command used

```
curl -F profile="/api/profile/e52f5ddc-d005-4d22-ae49-984a32012fdd/"     -F image="pic2.jpg" -F title="post" -F description="some description"  http://localhost/api/post/ -v
```

The object is created in the database with the filename, but there is no file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

// PostResource needed an additional field and the value of attribute should match the field  name in the model

```
image = fields.FileField(attribute='image')
```

//The upload_to parameter should contain a location that already exists or you will get an error

```
image = models.FileField(upload_to='/images/')
```

//The image field used in the curl command needed to be changed to look like this

```
-F "image=@someimage.jpg"
```

If anyone else has a problem getting this to work I hope you stumble across this post and find your solution.